# Retrieve PDF file from Sharepoint 2010 using Context

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model, url, file

Am struggling to get a pdf file from a Sharepoint 2010 site, I have managed to get a list of entries and found the file details.

How do I now download the file? I got a root folder file downloaded but this file is deep in many folders(with spaces!) within Sharepoint and I could not get right context.

Can someone guide me how to get the file?

I get an error on this line at when I try to access the file and save it;

```
var fileRef = oListItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;


private static void camlTest()
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://SPsite/Departments/sales/salesshelf/");
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Target Folder");
        clientContext.Load(spList);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        if (spList != null && spList.ItemCount > 0)
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'> <Query> <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq></Where> 
                                </Query> <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='_dlc_DocIdUrl' /><FieldRef Name='_dlc_DocId' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><FieldRef Name='LinkFilenameNoMenu' /><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' /><FieldRef Name='ParentLeafName' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='DocIcon' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /></ViewFields> </View>";

            ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("List Count: {0} ", listItems.Count);

            foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItems)
            {
                string spFilename = (string)oListItem["FileLeafRef"];
                string spRelativePathFilename = (string)oListItem["FileRef"];

                //Ignore     /Archive/
                if (checkForArchivePath(spRelativePathFilename)==false)
                {
                    //Check for file name
                    if (spFilename == "TargetPDF.pdf")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Passed:   ID: {0} \nFileLeafRef/Filename: {1} \nFileRef/Path: {2}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["FileLeafRef"], oListItem["FileRef"]);


                        var fileRef = oListItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                        var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
                        var fileName = Path.Combine("C:\\LocalDir\\", (string)oListItem.File.Name);
                        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                        {
                            fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of coffee, hair pulling etc it turned out it was just lifting the File Ref value and the file came down

```
var fileRef = (string)oListItem["FileRef"];
```